# Why does my nohup bash script reading in file always stop outputting count around 6k before end of file?

Tags: linux, bash, centos7, nohup

I use nohup to run a bash script to read in each line of a file (and extract info I need). I've used it on multiple files with different line sizes, mostly between 50k and 100k. But no matter how many lines my file is, nohup always stops outputting info around 6k before the last line.

my script called: fetchStuff.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

urlFile=$1
myHost='http://example.com'
useragent='me'
count=0
total_lines=$(wc -l < $urlFile)

while read url; do
    if [[ "$url" == *html ]]; then continue; fi

    reqURL=${myHost}${url}
    stuffInfo=$(curl -s -XGET -A "$useragent" "$reqURL" | jq -r '.stuff')
    [ "$stuffInfo" != "null" ] && echo ${stuffInfo/unwanted_garbage/} >> newversion-${urlFile}
    ((count++))
    if [ $(( $count%20 )) -eq 0 ]
    then
        sleep 1
    fi
    if [ $(( $count%100 )) -eq 0 ]; then echo "$urlFile read ${count} of $total_lines"; fi
done < $urlFile
```

I call it like so: `nohup ./fetchStuff.sh file1.txt &`
I get count info in nohup.out, e.g. "file1 read 100 of 60000", "file1 read 200 of 60000", etc.
But it always stops around 6k before end of file.

When I do `tail nohup.out` each time after running the script on the file, I get these as the last line in nohup.out:

```
file1.txt read 90000 of 96317  
file2.txt read 68000 of 73376  
file3.txt read 85000 of 91722  
file4.txt read 93000 of 99757
```

I can't figure out why it always stops around 6k before end of file. (I put the sleep timer in to avoid flooding the api w/a lot of requests).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loops skips lines that end with `html`, and they're not counted in `$count`. So I'll bet there are 6317 lines in `file1.txt` that end with `html`, 5376 in `file2.txt`, and so on.

If you want `$count` to include them, put `((count++))` before the `if` statement that checks the suffix.

```
while read url; do
    ((count++))
    if [[ "$url" == *html ]]; then continue; fi

    reqURL=${myHost}${url}
    stuffInfo=$(curl -s -XGET -A "$useragent" "$reqURL" | jq -r '.stuff')
    [ "$stuffInfo" != "null" ] && echo ${stuffInfo/unwanted_garbage/} >> newversion-${urlFile}
    if [ $(( $count%20 )) -eq 0 ]
    then
        sleep 1
    fi
    if [ $(( $count%100 )) -eq 0 ]; then echo "$urlFile read ${count} of $total_lines"; fi
done < $urlFile
```

Alternatively you could leave them out of `total_lines` with:

```
total_lines=$(grep -c -v 'html$' "$urlFile")
```

And you could do away with the `if` statement by using

```
grep -v 'html$' "$urlFile" | while read url; do
    ...
done
```

Comment: I figured. I literally just thought about the skip line minutes after posting my question! "Rubber Ducking" as they say.